# WPF TreeView data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I am very new to WPF, although I have already heard some concepts of it, like Model-View-ViewModel. I want to start learning WPF by doing a small program.

In the program I have a TreeView to display directories (e.g. My Documents, Computer etc.). I can easily develop a class for the data, which is the DirectoryModel

```
class DirectoryModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DirectoryInfo directory;
    private FileInfo file;

    private DirectoryModel(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        //...
    }

    private DirectoryModel(FileInfo file)
    {
        //...
    }

    public static DirectoryModel[] RootDirs()
    {
        //...
    }

    public DirectoryModel[] SubDirs()
    {
        //...
    }

    public DirectoryModel[] Files()
    {
        //...
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.directory != null)
            return this.directory.Name;
        else
            return this.file.Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Now I want to bind this model to the tree view. I have read several articles about binding data, from MSDN and CodeProject, but I still don't catch the key! I read something about creating a binding in XAML, and there one just writes something like `<c:MyData x:Key="myDataSource"/>`, but where is this `myDataSource` come from? As the first letter is not capitalized, I assume it is a variable of some type, but there is no definition or declaration or mention about this.

I have read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode), but there are many things not clear to me (like ItemTemplate, ItemContainerStyle etc.). My feeling is, it seems there are many different ways to do the binding, and different blogs or article use different approaches.

So my question is, how do I define a model class, and create a varible of that class and bind it to a control (here tree view)? Or I want to know, what is the standard approach to bind data in WPF, if there is any?

Answer (score 0):

To start with you can only bind to the public properties (at the moment you only have methods in your VM). The properties should implement the property changed event.
In your View.xaml.cs in constructor:

```
this.DataContext = new DirectoryModel ();
```

and obviously in your view.xaml you have to create the bindings e.g.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyPropertyFromViewModel}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one detail that I should know about. But I am still not clear, how to make the link between a varible of the model type and the control.

Comment: Since you are still learning maybe you could have a look at this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ab5f02f-0c54-453c-b437-8e8d57eb9942 I have never used it myself but I've heard it's good starting point.

Comment: It is still not clear about how the binding works. I think like this way: I have a model and a tree view, I could specify that each item would be bound to one model (a directory or a file), whenever an item is expanded, all the submodels (subdirectories and files) would be created and returned to the tree view, so that the tree view can also update the view of all these diretories and files.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I hope I can get some benefits from the box.